# FTPing file without referencing physical directory

Tags: java, web-services, ftp, httpclient

Please, help.
I have a java program that currently reads a list of files from physical directory (shared) and while reading, creating output files - also on the shared location.
So, for several files read, there can be a a single output file.
New requirements came to take the files from that output location and ftp them to a given ftp server
**The caveat is**:  The ftp procedure is done by microservice that most likely runs on the machines which do not have access to the output folder.  So, I am making a call to a service, not using FTP API (Appache, or etc..) internally.
Is it possible to send a OutputStream (byteOutputStream, or ObjectOutputStream) over an http call?  If so, how?
I know how to ftp the files from within my application, but the goal is .. to make a microservice call (webservice call, for what it matters, since my application is a plain old core java app).

Comment: I suppose what I am confused about is are your micro-services that are trying to pass the files clients or servers?

Answer (score 0):

I had a (rather different) project recently, however it also had the requirement to write to a `http response`.
I used this approach which works in my case:

```
try (OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream()) {

      final PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
```

Then after that, I write to the `PrintWriter` `w`.

Comment: I think it is different. 
I need to read a file locally and write it TO the HTTP (Service) location, so that that micro-service can obtain a file content, without having to know the local folders

Comment: So perhaps I should explain the context of my issue, I was creating csv content on the server. This had to be returned to the user's browser over http(s). So I could use the code I mentioned earlier, and this would deliver the data over http(s) to the user, no knowledge of folders required ... it is just http content.  
I don't have much knowledge of micro-services, are they much different from mini-servers/clients (depending on which direction the communication is going?)